# SQL Sort and update alpha numeric column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column that is alphanumeric and I ordered it and everything is all right. My problem is that the result of alpha numeric column look like this when some classes are missing in the `select` query:

```
02 - buyers
03 - sellers
05 - customers
07 - xxxx
12 - yyyyyy
```

How can I reorder this with the right order:

```
01 - buyers
02 - sellers
03 - customers
04 - xxxx
05 - yyyyyy
```

Thanks.

Comment: `row_number()`?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking, the order is the same, its the number that is different. Is it a question about numbering rather than actual sorting? Where does the number come from?

Comment: @HoneyBadger yes this is exactly what i want, the number come from a code column that i concat with that column

Comment: Don't bother. Keep the current values. Renumbering items can end up in a true mess.

Comment: @DaleK how can i do it with row_number() !

Comment: Check the docs - they explain how to us it.

Comment: @jarlh i asked the question cause i already end up in a mess :D so i should just let it like this

Comment: try this: https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-window-functions/sql-server-row_number-function/

Comment: @DaleK ok i'll check it and back with the result. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use a temporary table with an auto-id field.

```
create table tmpNumTable(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, name String)

insert into tmpNumTable(name) select name from clientType

select * from tmpNumTable
```

The syntax may differ depending on the language.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select row_number() over (order by col1), col2
from t
order by col1;
```